# Having display issues during install?

Tags: system-installation, display

I am downloading elementary OS for the first time. I made the bootable usb and booted into it via UEFI USB from my bios. Then I selected *Install elementary OS, after this my screen goes black for a few seconds then turns off and gives me nothing, but my computer stays on and I have to hold power for it to turn off. I have a gtx 970 with my screen connected to a dvi port, and another screen connected to my motherboard vga, incase this was the issue. The GNU GRUB screen is visible on my screen attached to my gpu. I am new to this and excited! Help?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue:

1. Go to: your-usb-drive/boot/grub,
2. Open `grub.cfg` file to edit
3. In each menuentry in line linux add before `quiet splash ---` text `nomodeset`, so line ending will be like: `nomodeset quiet splash ---`
4. Save and after on running from USB you will be ok with display

I also have gtx 970 and this helped for me